# Calculate logarithm of a raster?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm trying to calculate the logarithm of each cell in a raster. Is there a way to do this with F/OSS GIS? gdal_calc.py only has basic operators and the QGIS raster calculator feature doesn't seem to have a log function either.

I suppose I could still look into PostGIS raster functions but I'd prefer something that I could easily visualize in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
gdal_calc.py -A test.tif --calc "log(A)" --type Float32 --outfile log_test.tif
```

Other available solutions with FOSS GIS in order to calculate the logarithm of a raster (just to name a few):

- **r.mapcalc** in GRASS GIS;
- **Grid calculator** in SAGA;
- **Raster calculator** in SEXTANTE for gvSIG;
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each cell of the raster and use the math module to get the logarithm. Something like this:

```
import gdal
import math

dataset = gdal.Open( 'test.tif')

cols = dataset.RasterXSize
rows = dataset.RasterYSize

band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
for row in data:
    for item in row:
        value = math.log10(item)
        print value
        # write value to new dataset
```